# How can a minimum order quantity be implemented in orocommerce 4.1?

Tags: orocommerce

We want to use the new OroCommerce 4.1 Community Version. How to implement a way to set a minimum order value including the display of the difference to the minimum order value

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Inventory Quantity Limitations](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/commerce/inventory/limitations/) are configurable out of the box in OroCommerce 4.1 Community Edition.

### Update

If you want to limit the checkout process to the minimum order value, take a look at the [alternative checkout](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/tree/master/src/Oro/Bundle/AlternativeCheckoutBundle). This is an example of a checkout customization with the similar behaviour.

There is an order approval threshold.
https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/workflows/system-workflows/alternative-checkout/

But in your case, you should have different condition operator here
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/4.1.1/src/Oro/Bundle/AlternativeCheckoutBundle/Condition/OrderTotalLimit.php#L66

Comment: Thank you.
I'm looking for a setting option for the minimum order value, not for the minimum order quantit. Can you help me?